# Convert NLTK LazySubsequence to a list

Tags: python, nltk

Is there any NLTK built-in functions to convert an NLTK LazySubsequence to a list?

E.g.

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
corpus = brown.sents()
LS = corpus[0:250]
print('type(corpus)[0:250]: {0}'.format(type(LS)))
```

returns `type(corpus)[0:250]: <class 'nltk.util.LazySubsequence'>`.

I know I could convert looping around e.g. as follows with `convert_LazySubsequence_to_list()`, but I wonder whether NLTK offers any native way to cast to a Python list:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown

def convert_LazySubsequence_to_list(LS):
    corpus = []
    for s in LS:
        corpus.append(s)
    return corpus

corpus = brown.sents()
LS = corpus[0:250]
print('type(corpus)[0:250]: {0}'.format(type(LS)))

my_list = convert_LazySubsequence_to_list(LS)
print('type(my_list): {0}'.format(type(my_list)))
```

outputs

```
type(corpus)[0:250]: <class 'nltk.util.LazySubsequence'>
type(my_list): <type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is easier than you might think

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> corpus = brown.sents()
>>> LS = corpus[0:250]
>>> print('type(corpus)[0:250]: {0}'.format(type(LS)))
type(corpus)[0:250]: <class 'nltk.util.LazySubsequence'>
>>> my_list = list(LS)
>>> print('type(my_list): {0}'.format(type(my_list)))
type(my_list): <class 'list'>
```

No need for any special NLTK functions. Pythons built in `list()` can do it for you.

Comment: Good catch, I forgot (A LazySubsequence is iterable => one can use list() on it) :) Thanks!